# Bootstrapping confidence intervals and mean values for Log Response Ratio

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to bootstrap 95% CIs and mean values for measurements in order to examine the effect size of a treatment. The method I want to use is called LnRR or Logarithmic Response Ratio ([1](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1469-185X.2007.00027.x/abstract?systemMessage=Wiley%20Online%20Library%20will%20be%20disrupted%20on%2027%20October%20from%2010:00-12:00%20BST%20%2805:00-07:00%20EDT%29%20for%20essential%20maintenance), [2](http://www.esajournals.org/doi/abs/10.1890/0012-9658%281999%29080%5B1150%3aTMAORR%5D2.0.CO;2), [3](http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi/10.1371/journal.pone.0002400)). It's calculated simply by `Log(Response to treatment / Response to control)`. If the 95% CIs are not overlapping with 0, there is more than 95% probability for an effect naturally. Negative LnRR means that treatment has a negative effect.

The bootstrapping function in boot package is kind of confusing and I am struggling to calculate 95%  CI's and mean values. I have tried following:

```
library(boot)
set.seed(2)
dat <- data.frame(treatment = rnorm(10, 1.2, 0.4), control = rnorm(10, 1.5, 0.3))

boot(dat, function(x) log(x[,1]/x[,2]), R = 999) # Because LnRR = log(dat[,1]/dat[,2])
```

I am clearly doing something wrong. How can I bootstrap confidence intervals (boot.ci) for this type of function? I am sure that the answer is [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html), but for some reason, I just can't understand how to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree that the `boot` synatax is a little confusing, at first. The issue is that you need to write a function that takes both your data, AND a vector i which contains the indices to subsample. Let's rewrite your function explicitly to make it clearer:

```
yourFun <- function(x, i) {
  xSub <- x[i, ] #resample x
  LnRR <- log(xSub[, 1]/xSub[ ,2])
  return(mean(LnRR))
}
```

Then call boot in more-or-less the same way that you did:

```
b <- boot(dat, yourFun, R=999)
plot(b) #always worth looking at

#Calculate ci's
boot.ci(b)
```